# Matching (and removing) words that only consist of special characters

Tags: regex

I'd like to match "words", i.e., strings surrounded by whitespace or strings located at the beginning or end of a text, but that only consist of special characters.

I came up with the following pattern but unfortunately it doesn't match what I'm expecting it to:

```
((?<!\w)\W(?!\w))+
```

For the following input:

```
word1 !!!$$£@€${/// word3 word€€}}}==4 word5 @£]][{
```

I'd like the following string returned after having all matches removed (word #2 and #6):

```
word1 word3 word€€}}}==4 word5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask for is basically

```
(?<!\S)\W+(?!\S)
```

where

- `(?<!\S)` - matches start of string or a location right after a whitespace char
- `\W+` - 0+ non-word chars
- `(?!\S)` -  matches end of string or a location right before a whitespace char.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6vwMgd/1).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm using .NET, so the possessive quantifiers can be emulated by using atomic groups. What's the difference between #2, #3 and #4?

Comment: @silkfire Actually, I was not sure you really need to remove the whitespace before the match, thus removed the comment, but if you do, `\s*(?<!\S)\W+(?!\S)` will work. You may also use ``\s*(?<!\S)[^\w\s]\W*(?!\S)``, it will make matching smoother since `[^\w\s]` matches any non-word char except whitespace, so `\s*` will surely stop before the text matched with `[^\w\s]`.